# how to input values at chartjs labels?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, chart.js, label

1. i want to make it horizental at my value- lab(ex : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7...) and
   why print array vertical in chartjs?
2. why don't print my value my value - op3? (360.4,360.4,360.4,360.4,360.4,360.4)

my graph
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3epLA.png)

that's my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMPU3.png)

in my console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLkn1.png)

json data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c33s.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your code, `lab` is an `array` but it should be a `string`.

Either you create `lab` as a `string` from scratch or you convert the `lab` `array` into a `string` through [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) as follows:

```
data: {
  labels: [lab.join(', '), 9, 10],
  ...
```

Comment: i prreciate to your reply
and I could find another way

it's a spread operator.
   >>>>>>>>>       
labels: [
1,2,3,4,5, ...lab
]